# How do I do this process on a GPU to improve search speed?

Tags: python, vector, gpu

I have a vector with size 512, and I want to compare it to 30,000 similar items.

How do I do this process on a GPU to improve the search speed?
This is part of a code that runs on GPU and slows down the execution of the entire code because the search is carried over to CPU.

My python code for loading dataset:

```
all_files = glob.glob("/home/hbr-ubuntu/qqww/Dataset/*.out")
f3=[]
n3=[]
for t in all_files:
    f2 = np.loadtxt(t,dtype='float32',delimiter=',' )
    f3.append(f2)
    t = t.replace("/home/hbr-ubuntu/qqww/Dataset/", "")
    t = t.replace(".out", "")
    n3.append(t)
```

Search snippet code:

```
for r in f3:         
        sim = cp.dot(r, img_feature.T)
        if sim > 0.4:
        print('sim is', sim)
```

Best Regards.

Comment: It depends. Maybe try using PyTorch?

Comment: Can use pycuda, or even easier - cupy. Comparsion is a data-intensive operation though, so I wouldn't expect much speedup (although I don't really have experience)